# AWS Athena CTAS query failing, suggests emptying empty bucket

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I am running a "CREATE TABLE AS SELECT (CTAS) query" (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas.html), query copied at bottom. I am getting the following error message:

```
HIVE_PATH_ALREADY_EXISTS: Target directory for table 'default.openaq_processed' already exists:
 s3://<processed-data-bucketname>/. You may need to manually clean the data at location 
's3://<athena-query-results-bucketname>/Unsaved/2021/04/29/tables/82025a35-8867-4865-8f42-f40adb6bee4c' 
before retrying. Athena will not delete data in your account.

This query ran against the "default" database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the
 error message on our forum or contact customer support with Query Id: 82025a35-8867-4865-8f42-f40adb6bee4c.
```

The AWS knowledge center page on this error (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/athena-hive-path-already-exists/), like the error message above, suggests that the fix is to ensure the location used to store the query results must be empty.

But it already is. In fact there's no `tables/` prefix/folder in `s3://<athena-query-results-bucketname>/Unsaved/2021/04/29/`, and the `s3://<processed-data-bucketname>/` bucket is totally empty.

I've posted the question on the AWS forum but have received no responses. How might I get this CTAS query to succeed?

### Update

The query that throws the error:

```
CREATE TABLE openaq_processed
WITH (format='PARQUET', 
parquet_compression='SNAPPY', 
partitioned_by=array['country', 'parameter'], 
external_location = '<processed-data-bucketname>') 
AS
SELECT date_utc as date_utc_str,
date_local as date_local_str,
CAST(from_iso8601_timestamp(date_utc) as timestamp) as timestamp_utc,
CAST(from_iso8601_timestamp(date_local) as timestamp) as timestamp_local,
"location",  -- location is a reserved word for Athena, needs quotes
value,
unit,
city,
attribution,
averagingperiod,
coordinates."latitude" as latitude,
coordinates."longitude" as longitude,
sourcename,
sourcetype,
mobile,
country,
parameter
FROM openaq_pq2_tables
```

Comment: can you post your CTAS query? In particular the `external_location` option

Comment: thanks for responding, Nicolas. updated question with query above.

Comment: the error is telling you that the external location isn't empty. Can you try with a brand new bucket for testing? if it works I'd quintuple check the original s3 location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I sprung for AWS Developer Support and asked this question. The response I got, which indeed fixed the error, was to create a folder within my `external_location` bucket. Not sure why this is necessary but apparently it is.

So, from shell:
`$ aws s3 mb s3://<processed-data-bucketname>/processed_data/`

(`mb` above stands for "make bucket").

Then updating `external_location = 's3://<processed-data-bucketname>'` in the query above to
`external_location = 's3://<processed-data-bucketname>/processed_data/')`